# Continuous updates in PowerBI report

Tags: powerbi, powerapps

I am working on a report in PowerBI which has a table and a Power App (included via the PowerApp-Widget). Both table and app use the same data imported from an Excel-file on OneDrive, the App is able to change the data. I am currently working on a published version of the report in the PowerBI service.

My requirement is that changes made to the data with the Power App should immediately be visible in the table without needing to reload the page. Is there a way to achieve this?
The PowerBI API doesn't seem to offer such a function, also working with DirectQuery doesn't give me the required result.

Comment: The API gives you [Post Rows In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postrowsingroup), but as Alexis already told you, you will have to create a push dataset for that, by using [Post Dataset In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdatasetingroup) API. Then you can create a dashboard tile from this dataset and it will update near real time (based on my experience, with about 2-3 seconds delay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get live data like that is with [Real-time streaming in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming).

You probably want to use a Power BI REST API to create a push dataset.